# Subroutines on IBM Q (ERROR_RUNNING_JOB returned)

Tags: ibm-q-experience, qasm

I wrote following code in QASM editor on IBM Q web interface (note ccu1 is controlled-controlled U1 gate):

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";

gate ccu1 ( p ) c1, c2, t  {
  cu1 ( p / 2 ) c1, c2;
  cx c2, t;
  cu1 ( - p / 2 ) c1, t;
  cx c2, t;
  cu1 ( p / 2 ) c1, t;
}

qreg q[4];
creg c[4];

h q[0];
h q[1];
h q[2];
h q[3];

ccu1(pi) q[0],q[1],q[2];

id q[3];
measure q[3] -> c[3];
```

When I look to visualization of a state vector, everything is fine. However, when I tried to run the code on simulator I got error `ERROR_RUNNING_JOB`. There is also a status message `Error in transpilation process. [1003]` on results page.

I suspect that the issue is caused by subroutine (a `gate` statement at the beginning of the code).

**Could anyone please help me solve the issue?**

*Note, I know that it is possible to use subroutine in Qiskit, but I am interested in QASM*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just realized that web interface of IBM Q was updated and custom gates, i.e.

```
gate ccu1 ( p ) c1, c2, t  {
  cu1 ( p / 2 ) c1, c2;
  cx c2, t;
  cu1 ( - p / 2 ) c1, t;
  cx c2, t;
  cu1 ( p / 2 ) c1, t;
},
```

is correctly transpiled to gates used in the custom gate and subsequently to basic gate set used on IBM Q.

**Overall, custom gate functionality is now available in QASM**.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help. I have tried the code and it worked:

I created a new file named `ccu1_circuit.qasm` with the instruction written in the question. Then in a separate Python file, I have written:

```
from qiskit import *

circuit = QuantumCircuit.from_qasm_file('/...The path.../ccu1_circuit.qasm')

backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
print(execute(circuit, backend=backend, shots=1024).result().get_counts())
```

Here is the output:

`{'1000': 524, '0000': 500}`

Also, I noticed that when I tried to run `print(circuit.qasm())` I have found `ccu1` in the instructions (not its decomposition written in the `.qasm` file).

Comment: Thanks Davit, I know that it is not a problem in Qiskit. However, I would like to run the code in IBM Q web interface as it is more suitable for presentations etc.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand correctly. I tried with the web interface (Circuit Composer) and there was an ERROR_TRANSPILING_JOB (don't know why we have different errors). I tried also with different `gate` definitions, still, the same error.

Comment: Just solved! See below.